# Получить данные из БД по строковому имени модели (сущности)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть два класса - модели:

```
public class Products
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}

public class Customers
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

Есть две функции, которые извлекают из БД данные, соответствующие моделям:

```
    public IEnumerable<Products> GetAllProducts()
    {
        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            return db.Products.ToList();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customers> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            return db.Customers.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Они работают хорошо, но имеется естественное желание вместо двух жестко заданных функций, сделать одну гибкую, которая в качестве параметра принимала бы допустим имя модели, и в зависимости от него получала из базы нужные данные:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetAll(string modelName)
```

Вопрос в том, как использовать это строковое имя: string modelName = "Products" в конструкции:

```
        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            return db.<modelName>.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: От некоторых желаний нужно избавляться. Как минимум, ваша система потеряет возможность находить ошибки во время компиляции и при изменении модели, вы будете их получить в режиме выполнения. А такие ошибки проявляются внезапно, их гораздо сложнее искать и исправлять. Второе, вы теперь вручную будете переводить тип object к нужному типу в коллекции. А так ваша задача должна решаться шаблонами. Если хотите что-то унифицированное, то посмотрите на паттерн Репозиторий: https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/11.php

Comment: `имеется естественное желание` если это единственная причина городить такой костыль, то гасите это желание, этот код будет только мешать.